# In (Git)bash, set environment variable with special characters in key

Tags: bash, environment-variables, git-bash

In git bash (on windows) how can I set an environment variable with special characters in the key? Like `some.var:`.
The following does not work: `export "some.var:"=123`

Comment: You really should have included why you need to do this since it smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: well TBH it's something we've been using for years in production apps, which suddenly broke and I needed to test it - so it seems like discussing the reasoning for it would be a waste at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`export` requires a valid `bash` identifier, so it can only define a subset of legal environment strings.

If you have a program that requires a name that is not a valid identifier, you'll need to use an external program to create the necessary environment. For example:

```
$ env -i "some.var:=123" env
some.var:=123
```

`env` by itself reports its inherited environment. With a command, it runs that command in a possibly modified environment. `-i` clears the initial environment (so that we aren't flooded with irrelevant environment string; in practice, you can omit it if you want to inherit the current environment as well), and the string defines a name `some.var:` to have the value `123`).

Comment: thanks, this works, but is there a way to persist this variable so I don't need to redefine it before every command?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; the shell itself has no way of creating environment variables other than exporting ordinary shell variables. You would need to start your shell using this technique, inheriting the value from the parent rather then setting them via your shell configuration files.

Comment: In practice, you could define a wrapper around the command you want to run, something like `my_cmd () { env "some.var:=123" my_cmd; }`. (No recursion here, as `env` will be looking for a command in your path, not a shell function of the same name.)